# apache2 config include folder path into URL

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, config

My current apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin admin@example.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/lwiki
     ServerName wikiserver.internal
     ServerAlias wikiserver

     <Directory /var/www/html/lwiki>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

At the moment when browsing to `wikiserver.internal` the index of folder `/var/www/html/lwiki` is called, as expected.

Because I've migrated the wiki from an old machine I would need to make sure the folder `lwiki` is included inside the URL too.

For example:

```
http://wikiserver.internal/index.php
```

should be shown inside navigationbar of browser as

```
http://wikiserver.internal/lwiki/index.php
```

How to make sure the `lwiki` folder should be included to all URLs for sure.

Comment: Yes, sounds like a plan. You forgot to ask a question through, I am afraid...

Comment: If the question were "how to achieve that?", then the answer is: you change the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` by removing the `lwiki` folder from it and then add a redirection rule for all requests _not_ having a path that starts with the `/lwiki/` prefix. You will find many, many existing answers here on SO that demonstrate such rule. Though I personally would always recommend to start by looking into the documentation which is, as typical for OpenSource software, of excellent quality and comes with great examples: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: @arkascha Thanks, any idea for an example of the rewrite rule itself? Fining tons of different variants. Yes, your guess was correct regarding my question, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the comments to the question I would say this should point you into the right direction:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/lwiki/
RewriteRule ^ /lwiki%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301,END]
```

You certainly also need to take care of two additional aspects:

1. the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` must *not* contain the trailing folder `/lwiki` and more, so should only be `DocumentRoot /var/www/html`.
2. you need to make sure that the redirection rules are implemented at a location where they are actually considered by the http server and
3. you need to make sure that your wiki logic delivers *relative* internal references so that it works correctly *without* all references having to be redirected.

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).